# How common is it for public companies in US to sue each other regarding patent?

Tags: patent-infringement

I want a rough estimate and does not really need the exact number. Is it more than 500 per year overall? more than 100?

So I want to know how common is it for these companies to litigate each other.

Comment: In the US or worldwide? An interesting question, but I’m not sure we have any more insight than you’ll get from searching Google.

Comment: @EricS I'm interested in US

Answer (score 0):

It's much more than 500 per year but the number varies year to year and the rate has grown considerably from 2009. You might like to peruse this document:

https://www.wipo.int/edocs/pubdocs/en/wipo_pub_941_2018-chapter1.pdf

It covers more than US activity but you'll find US-specific charts and commentary.

Comment: Welcome to ask patents! It is encouraged to summarize the main points of external sources in case the original document ceases to be accessible.

Comment: So is it for public companies suing public companies?